Pagination of Data with Apollo GraphQL and SSR NextJS pages
I am using Next.js v14, graphql, ApolloClient and ApolloGraphQL Experimental support for NextJS
{
    "@apollo/client": "^3.12.0-rc.3",
    "@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support": "^0.11.6",
}

I have been following this blog post so far on how to use ApolloClient with NextJS v13+ https://www.apollographql.com/blog/how-to-use-apollo-client-with-next-js-13.
I am trying to make a SSR front page that showcases user posts. It is paginated, such that
it initially loads X amount and then loads more if the user chooses to load more.
However, I am confused on how to implement pagination. Looking at the docs on pagination
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/pagination/core-api#the-fetchmore-function.
It's easy to follow, however, it's using useQuery from @apollo/client, which only works
on csr components. Because my page is SSR, using the code from the first blog, I have to use getClient().query(), but this does not have any fetchMore() methods on the response result. I implemented a fetchMore function that I think would work, but because the page is SSR, button's can't have onClick handlers. Am I missing something? What's the solution? I want to keep the retrieval of the data on the server.
Here is my relevant code:
import { getClient } from '@/lib/apollo';
import { gql } from '@apollo/client';

const GET_ALL_POSTS = gql`
    query GetAllPosts($limit: Int!, $cursor: String) {
        posts(limit: $limit, cursor: $cursor) {
            posts {
                id
                title
            }
            hasMore
        }
    }
`;

export const revalidate = 0;

export default async function Home() {
    const queryResult = await getClient().query({
        query: GET_ALL_POSTS,
        variables: {
            limit: 10,
        },
    });

    // irrelevant code for handling loading state

    const data = queryResult.data?.posts;

    // example idea for fetching more, but can't have onClick for buttons with SSR
    async function fetchMore() {
        await getClient().query({
            query: GET_ALL_POSTS,
            variables: {
                limit: 10,
                cursor: data.posts[data.posts.length - 1].createdAt,
            },
        });

        getClient().cache.writeQuery({
            query: GET_ALL_POSTS,
            data: {
                posts: {
                    posts: [...data.posts, ...queryResult.data.posts.posts],
                    hasMore: queryResult.data.posts.hasMore,
                },
            },
        });
    }


    return (<div>
        // irrelevant code for showcasing posts
            {queryResult.data && data.hasMore && (
                <button
                    onClick={fetchMore}
                >
                    Load more
                </button>
            )}
    </div>);
}

I suppose even if I did have a fetchMore call available to me, the button would still not be able to call it since its SSR page and can't have an onClick event. So maybe just making it a CSR page is the correct thing to do. Is there no way to make all the queries run on the server?

Stuff like this will only work in Client Components - in your React Server components, every render starts off with a completely empty cache that isn't connected to any previous user request and, as you already noticed, you ship non-interactive HTML to the browser.
That said, you probably do not have any real reason to use React Server Components here in the first place - just use useSuspenseQuery in a Client Component. Client Components server-side render on first page load, too, but then they will continue interactively in the browser. (The Nextjs/Apollo package you linked to will ensure correct hydration in the browser).
That is probably what you want.

My reasoning for wanting it SSR is so that there is no load on the client initially and for SEO, so that when a bot crawls it, it doesn't get any empty loading page. I see that CSR servers are still rendered on the server on first load, however it still makes the GraphQL request on the client and has to wait for the data, which is not what I want ideally. Also from my understanding then, is the useQuery being run in both the client and server? Isn't that unnecessary (even if cached)?

I assumed useSuspenseQuery was only meant to allow for the Suspense element to be used, but would still query on the client. However, it seems it behaves exactly as I wanted (as described above)

Yeah, that's the whole purpose of the Apollo Client Next.js integration package :)
